# Use Database.upsert with external id field is not working on PricebookEntry object

Tags: upsert, pricebookentry

I need help to do a DML operation with external id field. I am using the below syntax, but it is throwing an error

```
Schema.SObjectField f = PricebookEntry.Fields.Product_Code__c;
Database.UpsertResult[] myResult = Database.upsert(insertList,f,false);
```

> **Error**: getErrors=(Database.Error[getFields=();getMessage=Product_Code__c not
>   specified;getStatusCode=MISSING_ARGUMENT;]);getId=null

Any help here is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It reads like you have one or more records that do not have a Product_Code__c field specified, hence the error. Make sure your data is correct.

Comment: Thanks, sfdcfox!